# Why is it called social media platforms?

Tags: word-usage

I thought media was plural, so why do we add platforms to the end of social media? Is it too be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual noun is "platform".  "Social media" is being used as an adjective, modifying the noun.  What kind of platform?  A social media platform.

If your confusion is regarding the meaning of platform, a platform is any means by which you can spread a message.  So if you want to spread a message, for example, an advertisement, you could use a television platform, a newspaper platform, or a social media platform.

"Social Media" is a similar construct.  "Media" is the noun, "social" is the adjective.  Media is the collective noun meaning means of delivering news, such as newspapers and television.  Social, as an adjective applied to media, means that unlike newspapers and television, this media is 2-way communication.  It's social.  A newspaper you can only read, television you can only watch, radio you can only hear, but social media is news that you can talk back to.

Examples of social media include Facebook, Twitter, Tumblr, and Reddit.  In each of these, anyone can create the news that others will encounter, and anyone can react or respond to that news.  It is social in nature.

Comment: could you also explain what social media means, please?

Comment: Certainly.  I've added it to my answer.